# HTML table in email signature changing sizes when viewed on IOs devices

Tags: html, css, ios, email, html-email

I've been having an issue where the signature we've built works on nearly everything except IOS devices like Iphone and Ipad. on those devices the second cell is much thinner than it's supposed to be, and I can't tell if it's because the first cell is too big or if something else is causing this.

I figured standard table HTML would be fairly universal, and I don't have any fancy code going in here, so I expect it's some sort of odd interaction in how it's being translated by the mail app.

I've tried making the cells one pixel shorter, in case it's somehow not liking how it fits in the full 600 pixel width table. No dice.

Any idea what might be causing this? Thanks a ton for any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<table style="width: 600px; border-collapse: collapse; font-family: Arial;">
    <tr style="width: 600px;">
        <td colspan="2" style="width: 314px; border-bottom: 2px solid #1a206c; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 8px; vertical-align: top; " >
            <span style="font-size: 18pt; font-weight: bold; color: #1a206c;">
                John Doe
                <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITIL" style="text-decoration: none;">
                    <img src="http://www.gosafe.com/signatures/personalcerts/itil.png" border="0" alt="Certification"/>
                </a>
            </span>
            <br>
            <span style="font-size: 11pt; font-weight: bold; color: #ff6400; line-height: 20px;">
                Senior Operating Officer
            </span>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" style="width: 284px; border-bottom: 2px solid #1a206c; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 8px; vertical-align: top;">
            <span style="font-size: 9pt; color: #1a206c; font-family: Arial;">
                <img src="https://www.gosafe.com/signatures/5-2021-images/tollfree.png" alt="Phone Number" vertical-align="center"/>
                <strong style="line-height: 20px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;555.555.5555</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <img src="https://www.gosafe.com/signatures/5-2021-images/mobile.png" border="0" alt="Mobile"/>
                <strong style="line-height: 20px;">&nbsp;555.555.5555</strong>
            </span>
            <br style="font-size: 9pt;" />
            <span style="font-size: 9pt; color: #1a206c; font-family: Arial; line-height: 20px; vertical-align: middle;">
                <img src="https://www.gosafe.com/signatures/5-2021-images/email.png" border="0" alt="Email"/>
                <strong style="line-height: 20px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;John_Doe@exampleguy.com</strong>
            </span>
            <span style="font-size: 9pt; color: #1a206c; font-family: Arial;"></span>
            <br style="font-size: 8pt;" />
            <span style="font-size: 9pt; color: #1a206c; font-family: Arial; margin-bottom: 0px;">
                <img src="https://www.gosafe.com/signatures/5-2021-images/location.png" border="0" alt="Location"/>
                <strong style="line-height: 20px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;3343 Main Street, Albany, New York, 33939</strong>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width: 600px;">
        <td style="width: 200px; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
            <a href="http://www.goSafe.com">
                <img src="https://www.gosafe.com/signatures/5-2021-images/goSafeLogo.png" border="0" alt="goSafe"/>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" style="width: 200px; padding-top: 5px; text-align: center;">
            <a title="Member of the AD Safety Network" style="text-decoration: none;" href="https://www.adhq.com">
                <img src="https://www.gosafe.com/signatures/5-2021-images/ADsnPerfect.png" border="0" alt="AD Safety Network"/>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
            <p style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial; text-decoration: none;" align="right">
                <a title="goSafe on LinkedIn" style="text-decoration: none;" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/948460">
                    <img src="https://www.gosafe.com/signatures/5-2021-images/li.png" border="0" alt="Linked In"/>
                </a>&nbsp;
                <a title="goSafe on FaceBook" style="text-decoration: none;" href="https://www.facebook.com/gosafesupply">
                    <img src="https://www.gosafe.com/signatures/5-2021-images/FB.png" border="0" alt="Facebook"/>
                </a> &nbsp;
                <a title="goSafe on Instagram" style="text-decoration: none;" href="https://www.instagram.com/gosafesupply">
                    <img src="https://www.gosafe.com/signatures/5-2021-images/ig.png" border="0" alt="Instagram"/>
                </a>&nbsp;
                <a title="goSafe on Twitter" style="text-decoration: none;" href="https://twitter.com/gosafesupply">
                    <img src="https://www.gosafe.com/signatures/5-2021-images/tw.png" border="0" alt="Twitter"/>
                </a>
                <br>
                <a href="http://www.goSafe.com" style="text-decoration: none;">
                    <span style="color: #ff6400;">
                        <strong title="">www.goSafe.com</strong>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width: 600px;">
        <td colspan="4">
            <p style="width: 600px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 10px; font-size: 7pt; color: #1a206c; font-family: Arial;">This email and any attachments may contain confidential or proprietary information, the review and usage of which is restricted to the sender and the intended recipient(s). If you are not the intended recipient, please contact the sender and delete all copies of this message and any attachments.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br /><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's 600px wide, and mobiles only have about 300px! So there is going to be downscaling or chopping or squeezing to compensate.

I'd suggest re-creating according to 'fluid design' principles.

Comment: Hmm... While this would explain the trouble with I-phone, it doesn't explain why it's having issues with I-pad, which should have more than 300 pixels to work with, or why it displays fine (albeit small) on android email apps like gmail and outlook.

Comment: Oh, also, I forgot to mention that when it is displayed on iphone or ipad, it still displays at the full 600px width, but for some reason it looks like the first cell has expanded to around 450 pixels in width, crushing the second cell to 150 pixels width. Both the figures I just gave you are estimates so I can explain what I'm seeing. Name and title, a huge honkin' gap, then the contact information.

Comment: "It displays fine (albeit small) on android" - which is because it applies a full-email downscale, because it's too wide. For the other issue, I suspect it is because of the colspans - which typically have problems with Outlook desktops. What you can do is nest the new row in a table, and then you can do away with colspans.